# How I avoid ambiguity in the use of "and"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, conjunctions, ambiguity

How do I avoid ambiguity in the use of "and"?

For example, the phrase:

> "demonstrative pronoun and adjective"

could mean both pronoun and adjective are demonstrative, or it could mean only demonstrative is for pronoun.

Is there a way to write this where the ambiguity is avoided?

Comment: Just reorder until you get what you want.  "adjective and demonstrative pronoun"

Comment: Thanks, but in the original sentence what is the meaning? that both are demonstrative?

Comment: It's ambiguous.  It could be either.  There's no rule that's going to resolve this; and keep in mind your reader/listener won't know the rule, or whether or not you know the rule.  Context may be a clue: are there demonstrative adjectives?  Consider: He had a fast car and a house; versus he had a fast car and motorcycle.

Comment: In first case, car is fast. But in second case? both or only the car?

Comment: Why do you write "... in the original sentence what is the meaning? that both are demonstrative?" after saying " 'demonstrative pronoun and adjective' could mean both pronoun and adjective are demonstrative, or it could mean [that] 'demonstrative' [only modifies] 'pronoun' "? Your own statement is ambiguous: 'the only accepted meaning could be either  ...' or 'neither meaning is impossible'. English strings are  often ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that "*adjective noun_1* and *noun_2*" on its own is ambiguous.

One approach to eliminate ambiguity when the adjective applies to both nouns is to distribute it:

> *adjective noun_1* and *adjective noun_2*

Some approaches to eliminate ambiguity when the adjective *doesn't* apply to both nouns are to add an article:

> a(n)/the *adjective noun_1* and a(n)/the *noun_2*

or to numbers the nouns:

> (1) *adjective noun_1* and (2) *noun_2*

or to place them on different lines:

> *adjective noun_1*; and
>
> *noun_2*

or (if possible) to reorder the list:

> *noun_2* and *adjective noun_1*

Comment: Thanks, but in this case: 
a(n)/the adjective noun_1 and a(n)/the noun_2

For example: A red car and a bicycle. It means that there is a red car and there is a bicycle or it means that there is a red car and there is a red bicycle?

Comment: "A red car and a bicycle" means that there is a bicycle and that there is a red car. (In other words, it does not imply that the bicycle is red.)