# Do the words “direct physical” modify the word “damage” in the following phrase “direct physical loss or damage”?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

Since “loss” and “damage” are stated in the disjunctive by the use of “or” I suspect the “damage is not modified by “direct physical”. I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: I'm especially interested in theories that prove my thesis. Thank you for you thoughts!

Comment: The 'Throw out your yellow socks and shirts' and 'Buy some red socks or shirts' scope-ambiguity is well known. That is, whether the lone modifier before the first noun in a conjunctive or disjunctive construction modifies only the first noun or both nouns is **indeterminate** (unless context disambiguates). Both readings are acceptable (though the ambiguity itself is eschewed according to Gricean maxims, and should be avoided). _This is true in general English usage, which is what ELU deals with, though legal readings, off-topic, may differ._  ...

Comment: As said last time (and you must not keep deleting and resubmitting the same question). There is a [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440362/how-i-avoid-ambiguity-in-the-use-of-and) for examples with the coordinator 'and'. // Copy kept; please do not delete / resubmit again.

Comment: I would like to see a context in which the adjectives are not redundant for “loss”. That said, though, in the most likely contexts, I would take “loss or damage” as a unit, damage being a weaker kind of loss.

Answer (score 1):

They modify both *loss* and *damage*.

It's important to consider a statement's context. Here, that's the only interpretation that makes sense. Aside from the question of what kind of loss or damage *isn't* direct or physical, it stands to reason that we have the same concerns about damage that we have about loss.

Don't get hung up on the word *or*. Loss is one thing. Damage is another. Combining them with an *and* would eliminate most situations, since it's not likely that someone would complain about the goods being both lost *and* damaged: If they're lost, you'll never know whether they're damaged or not.

Or care.